# Searching for an Webapp who shows website

Tags: web-apps, web-browser, url

I am searching for a Website similar to [Stumlbeupoon](https://www.stumbleupon.com/) who show me an other website in there. To be short: I want a browser as a webapp.

[image]

I need a website like these to hide the domain-name. As you see "www.cheeseandburger.com" is encapseled in "www.stumbleupon.com". The problem by stumbleupon is that is only shows websites random. I want a similar service where I can open a specific website in a service like these.

Comment: Could you add your use case? Is it for obfuscating the URL when someone looks over your shoulder, or don’t you want to connect to the site directly (i.e., a proxy), or …?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the proxy function of [ixquick](https://ixquick.com/).

It won't do JavaScript, Formulas and cross-site links but if you just want to look at a site and browse it a bit - it works.

e.G. If you can't visit the Wikipedia entry for "Food" you would go to ixquick and enter: `site:en.wikipedia.org Food` and then hit the link "proxy" next to the search result of the food article. (In German the link is "Anonym öffnen", so it might differ from "proxy" depending on the language you use.)

You can't just proxy anything through it, unfortunately, but anything that can be found through ixquick can.

[image: Screenshot of ixquick proxy]